# AngularJS variable not changing back in controller

Tags: html, angularjs

js:

```
$scope.hello = "hello world";
```

html:

```
<input ng-model="hello">
<label>{{hello}}</label>
```

It sets the label good on initializing but after that it stop updating. What's wrong?

Comment: you did properly as os per your code there were no clues for errors so i just updated my answer

Comment: So what leaded you to accept the above answer .. can you pls let me know whats wrong with my answer where i can improve  ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this in your controller:

```
$scope.system = {};
$scope.system.hello = 'hello world';
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you Go
 as per your code there were no clues for errors so i just answered with working code and some  definition of 2-way data-binding 
The updating is called `two-way binding` a good feature from angular .

Little Brief about 2 way data binding :-

> Two way data binding in angularjs framework is approach to synchronize
>   the data between model and view. What it means that if there is any
>   change happens in model ( Back-end ) then view ( front-end ) will be
>   updated and vice versa.

data binding docs [Angular data binding Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/databinding)

Sample Js: -

```
'use strict';
 var app = angular.module('mainApp', []);
app.controller('registerCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.hello='hello world';
 }]);
```

Html :-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="mainApp">

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="registerCtrl">

    <input type="text" ng-model="hello"/>
    {{hello}}

</body>

</html>
```

You properly Binded to the text box with model

plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/go9r3x?p=preview